# Creating Disney-style circular fireworks

Tags: particles, light, effects

How to create the curved firework which is at the end of the Disney's movie-intro?

I am talking about this (video link): https://youtu.be/k9bUTfFF3_4?t=20

Comment: Hello, you probably need to use an object that moves along a curve a drop particles

Comment: Yes. But as the "object" moves along the curve, the curve keeps glowing for some time...also the same for particles.

Comment: you can create a long subdivided cylinder, give it a Curve modifier so it follows along, give it a Displace modifier, also a material with a mix of transparency and emission with a noise as factor, so that it's not completely straight

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create a long cylinder for your trail, with a big spherical head, give it the following modifiers: *Subdivision Surface, Curve, Displace* (to give it a bit of bumps), also give it a particle system with an icosphere as particle in order to make it emit sparks:

[image]

[image]

Here is the kind of material you can give to your trail: a mix between *Emission* and *Transparent*, with a Noise as factor, also give it gradient transparency on X so that it fades:

[image]

File here: [image]